# Converting what seems to be a str from a np.array to a tensorflow comptatible object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to fit data from a csv file to a tf model.
The issue is that while extracting it in a pandas dataframe, those object types attributes don't seem to like any conversion and i don't know what and how to make it work for tensorflow.

Im loading a dataset from a csv file :

```
data= pd.read_csv("xxx.csv")
```

the dtypes are :

```
data.dtypes
```

Out[46]:

```
numDoc            int64axe0             objectaxe1             objectaxe2             objectaxe3             objectaxe4             objectmeilleurMot0     objectmeilleurMot1     objectmeilleurMot2     objectmeilleurMot3     objectmeilleurMot4     objectmeilleurMot5     objectmeilleurMot6     objectR2score         float64dtype: object
```

data.axe0 returns :

```
data.axe0
```

Out[47]:
0

```
[-1.93332896e-03 -3.83069858e-02  9.56007672e-...1      [-1.93332896e-03 -3.83069858e-02  9.56007672e-...2      [-1.93332896e-03 -3.83069858e-02  9.56007672e-...3      [-1.93332896e-03 -3.83069858e-02  9.56007672e-...4      [-1.93332896e-03 -3.83069858e-02  9.56007672e-...
```

data.axe0[0] returns :

```
data.axe0[0]
```

Out[48]:

```
'[-1.93332896e-03 -3.83069858e-02  9.56007672e-02  5.60412846e-02\n -2.02865094e-02 -7.77137650e-02 -1.25703788e-02  2.19811689e-02\n -2.52908713e-02 -1.86388640e-01  5.38185146e-02 -5.79157642e-02\n  6.90147723e-03  4.53204230e-02 -7.96977817e-02...]'
```

I tried to convert it into float but with no succces.

When i try to run my tensorflow fit function i get :

`Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported`

I'm not sure in what form i should transform it tbh.

Edit :

```
type(data.axe0[0])
Out[59]: str

type(data.axe0)
Out[60]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I managed to do it, i dont know if its the most efficient way :

```
np.fromstring(dataOri[col][axe].replace("\n","").replace("[","").replace("]",""), dtype=np.float, sep=' ')
```

But now i have :

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Comment: you have list (or rather `numpy.array) converted to string and you can't simply convert it to float again. You have to parse it: remove `[`, `]`, `\n`, `...` and later you can `split(" ")` to get list of strings, and later use `for`-loop to convert every string with number to float on list separatelly.

Comment: if you generated this file then you should change code which you used to save it because you create big mess instead of correct CSV

Comment: if you generated it with some function in numpy then better search in numpy some function to read it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your message, i have parsed it and managed to make it work but i have yet another error now, i will put my fix in the edit

Answer (score 0):

For any small CSV dataset the simplest way to train a TensorFlow model on it is to load it into memory as a pandas Dataframe or a NumPy array.

Follow these steps to see what is being missed out :

Load the dataset:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset_name.csv' or 'link', names=["column1","column2","column_n"])
```

then,

Convert them to a numpy array as pointed by the error :

```
Features = np.array(df.features)
```

Then use it in your model

a working example of your problem has been given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#:%7E:text=For%20any%20small%20CSV%20dataset,limited%2Drange%20floating%20point%20values.).